# Expected time of finishing the game (coin flips)

Tags: probability

The game is as follows:

Two players toss a coin each. Each player will get 1 dollar if his coin flip is head. A player will stop the game if he gained k dollar more than the opponent. What is the expected time of termination of the game?

I know different techniques can be used to solve the problem (for example Markov chain) and i am interested what kind of approaches can be taken in these kind of situation.

For reference, the question is a brain teaser I have found in a list of interview question.

Comment: Let $X_n$ be the number of heads for player 1 after $n$ flips and $Y_n$ be the number of heads for player 2 after $n$ flips. You are interested in $Z_n = X_n - Y_n$. Can you say something about the jump probabilities of $Z_n$? Edit: I guess I would use a Markov chain with absorbing states at $Z_n = \pm k$ with $Z_0 = 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the difference, this changes by $+1$ with probability $\frac14$, $-1$ with probability $\frac14$, and $+0$ with probability $\frac12$.

The expected time to hit a particular value will then be twice that of a random walk which  changes by $+1$ with probability $\frac12$, and $-1$ with probability $\frac12$.  And that question is well known to have an expected time to first hit $\pm k$ of $k^2$.

So the answer to your original question is $2k^2$.